# Excel - comparing a single value to splits/totals for that value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a sheet that tracks deliveries of a material in 30,000-40,000lb values.  On a "Delivered amounts" tab, I have:

```
Ticket 12345:  41250
Ticket 23456:  42200
Ticket 34567:  43000
```

On a separate tab, I say whether or not these entries have been billed and 
they may be split up.  So we may see Ticket 34567 used twice, with values of 21500 and 21500.

I'm wrestling with how to go about comparing all of these split entries to the original total.  If a table contains

```
Ticket 23456:  21100
Ticket 23456:  21100
Ticket 34567:  21500
Ticket 34567:  21500
Ticket 34567:  10000
```

Then it would look up each ticket entry, sum up the values and give a response of "Ticket 23456 matches the total and has been properly billed" and "Ticket 34567 has been over-billed, please recheck your figures."   Not with that specific text, but just a way to compare the split and totaled amounts to what the original value should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a pivot table from the data in the split table and then use a formula to compare with the original values.

[image]

Change the formula in D3 to something like

```
=IF(SUMIFS(J:J,I:I,B3)<C3,"underpaid","overpaid")
```

Edit: second thought: this can be done totally without the pivot table. Use the formula

```
=IF(SUMIFS(G:G,F:F,B3)<C3,"underpaid","overpaid")
```

Comment: I got completely distracted from coming back here, but just wanted to say thank you.  I opted for the Pivot Table approach but now that my overall sheet is running smoothly, I'm looking for ways to go back and reduce any unnecessary complexity, so I may be using the SUMIFS soon, too.  You're awesome.